# Overriding writeStreamHeader() to append objects to a single file

Tags: java

I need to append multiple objects in a single file in multiple sessions.

I searched for a fair amount of time and I got two solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379414/6528991).

1) Using List to get already written  objects from the file, add new objects to the List and rewriting the file.

2) Overriding `writeStreamHeader()`

I followed the second method i.e., overriding `writeStreamHeader()`.

He stated that

> A workaround is to subclass `ObjectOutputStream` and override
>   `writeStreamHeader()`. The overriding `writeStreamHeader()` should call
>   the super w`riteStreamHeader` method if it is the first write to the
>   file and it should call `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` if it is appending
>   to a pre-existing ObjectOutputStream within the file.

So I tried this

```
class ObjectOutput extends ObjectOutputStream
{
    protected ObjectOutput(OutputStream os) throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super(os);
    }

    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("abc.txt");
        if(file.exists())
        {
            reset();
        }
        else
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            super.writeStreamHeader();
        }

    }

}
```

When I try to read the objects from the file there is an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 79737200
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at Get.main(Get.java:11)
```

Then I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194656/appending-to-an-objectoutputstream#comment8987320_1195078)

Now, it worked perfectly!

So, what's wrong with the first code? I called the `super.writeStreamHeader()` when there is no file and the second method also calls the same method in the same scenario.

So,is there anything I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist you can't possibly enter this piece of code. It will have been created by `new FileOutputStream(...)` before this constructor executes.

Comment: @EJP yeah I completely missed that point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this too and still it will work fine**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
    public MyObjectOutputStream() throws IOException{
       super();
    }
    public MyObjectOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException{
        super(outputStream);
     }
   public void writeStreamHeader(){}
 }
```

The explanation for this is the same as the link to the solution you provided in the question itself.